# Use EntityFramework to load Items that have more than one subItem

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a class Item that contains a list of SubItems as shown below

```
public class Item
{
    public List<SubItem> SubItems
}
```

How can I use entity framework to load only those Items where the SubItems list has at least one Subitem?

Comment: `A where the SubItems list has at least one subitem?` - Please make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this as follows:

```
var items = dbContext.Set<Item>().Include(i => i.SubItems)
                 .Where(i => i.SubItems.Any()).ToList()
```